# see if a directory/file exists with spaces in the name

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, space, test-command

I want ot check if a path is a file or a directory. I know the path exists. The code below works as long as no spaces are in the path. How to make this work for names with spaces? I currently have a file with a name in it and cannot check if it exists remotely. code reads:

```
server=<serverip>
path="/var/lib/Fingerprint log.log"

if ssh root@$server test -d $path
then
    echo "Directory"
else
    echo "File"
fi
```

When I have a path with a space it fails saying

test: /var/lib/Fingerprint: binary operator expected

if path is /var/lib/Fingerprint log.log

Comment: Quote your variables. Always quote your variables.

Comment: @EtanReisner what is the SO convention to indicate issue is solved when a comment provides enough hints?

Comment: @Dinesh: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: @Dinesh Generally I get people telling me to write it as an answer. =) This issue just comes up enough that it didn't feel like it warranted Yet Another answer and I was (admittedly) too lazy to go find a good question to mark this a duplicate of.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't really one obvious duplicate *question*, but rather hundreds of questions that all have the same answer. This is a question that the OP could answer himself by reading the tips and suggestions on the `bash` tag's info page (which, unfortunately, is not easy that easy to find for someone not familiar with Stack Overflow).

Comment: Indeed. A high quality generic canonical question would be ideal here but I don't know of one and haven't had time to try to create one.

Answer (score 1):

As per the top most comment, you need to use "${path}" instead of $path.

Answer (score 0):

```
path="/var/lib/Fingerprint log.log"
ssh root@$server test -d $path
```

The short answer is that you should run ssh like this:

```
ssh root@$server test -d "'$path'"
or
ssh root@$server "test -d '$path'"
```

The double quotes ensure that the `$path` variable is expanded on the local system, and also that the single quotes are passed through to the remote system. The single quotes ensure that the value of `$path` is still treated as a single command-line argument on the remote system.

This is due to how ssh handles remote commands that are specified on its command line. First, it concatenates all of the relevant command-line arguments into a single space-separated string. Then it sends that string to the remote system, where it's run as a shell command.

For example:

```
$ dne='/var/does not exist'
$ ssh localhost ls $dne
ls: cannot access /var/does: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access not: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access exist: No such file or directory

$ ssh localhost ls "$dne"
ls: cannot access /var/does: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access not: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access exist: No such file or directory

$ ssh localhost ls "'$dne'"
ls: cannot access /var/does not exist: No such file or directory
```